# Give a error or redirect if the code doesn't exist in txt file

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a form page where the users must put a code that I send them by email, this form has as action file redirect.php, which contain this code:

```
<?php
header('Location: page.php?code='.$_POST['code']);
?>
```

now what I want to do with my form page is to show a error or to redirect to a page if the code they input on my form doesn's exist in code.txt file.

Is it possible that? And if is it how to do it?

**EDIT:**

I think that must be easier: I want that this form:

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
<input id="code" name="code" type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I want this form to pass to the page.php only if the value of input id="code" match values from code.txt

Comment: What does the test file look like and what have you tried?

Comment: I have a code.txt file which contain a code on each line. I don't know how to read this file with php or java to can show a error or redirect to other page if the code doesn't exist in code.txt file, because I asked here, I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript:

```
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function checkcode ( form )
{

  var pattern = /name="code" value="|code|code1|code2|"/g
  if (!pattern.test(form.code.value)) {
    alert( "The code is incorrect." );
    form.code.focus();
    return false ;
  }

  return true ;
}

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!in_array($_GET['code'], file('code.txt')) {
    echo "Error";
} 

//or

if(strpos(file_get_contents('code.txt'), $_GET['code']) === false) {
    echo "Error";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I will try to implement this! I'm not sure how to do it but I will try!